# Can't bubble up Json.Net exception to my middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm working on a kind of web-api. The parameters of my controller requests is automatically deserialized to dtos with Json.Net. I'm trying to bubble up the Json.Net deserializing errors to my ApiMiddleware.

```
var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
            options.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
            {
                var message = args.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = false;
                throw new ValidationException(message);
            };
        });
```

I supposed that the exception will buble up and my middleware will able to catch it and log the url of the request and deserializing error. But Json.Net catches all the inner throws by himself, so the only thing that comes to my middleware is "Current error context error is different to requested error”-exception.
I've explored about a dozen of questions somehow connected with my problem, but there was no solution.

So, does anybody know how to throw the ValidationException outside or make the original deserializing-exception delievered to my middleware? Thanks

Comment: As you mentioned, the error seems be caught and handled by Json.NET itself. We can not catch deserializing related exception error directly within middleware. But we can catch http 400 error based on response status in custom middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the ASP.NET Core source code, it seems that `NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter` is designed to suppress `JsonException`s and convert it into model state errors. One workaround to this issue in ASP.NET Core 3.1 is to set `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages` to `false`. This causes `JsonException`s to be captured on the model state, which you can then examine in an action filter and throw your own exceptions if you encounter one:

In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers(c => { c.Filters.Add(new JsonErrorActionFilter()); })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(c => { c.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false; });
```

And the action filter could be something like this:

```
public class JsonErrorActionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result == null && !context.ModelState.IsValid
            && HasJsonErrors(context.ModelState, out var jsonException))
        {
            throw new ValidationException(jsonException.Message);
        }
    }

    private static bool HasJsonErrors(ModelStateDictionary modelState, out Exception jsonException)
    {
        foreach (var entry in modelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var error in entry.Errors)
            {
                if (error.Exception is JsonException)
                {
                    jsonException = error.Exception;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        jsonException = null;
        return false;
    }

    // Set to a large negative value so it runs earlier than ModelStateInvalidFilter
    public int Order => -200000;
}
```

This is likely using `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages` in a way that it's not intended to be used, so the solution will probably break if you upgrade to a different version of ASP.NET Core. But for now it may get the job done.